# Using a Chrome Extension to listen for a network response on a NextJs website

Tags: reactjs, next.js, google-chrome-extension

Is it possible to listen for fetch network requests on a website and use the response in a Chrome extension? For example, I visit HTTP://website.com and it does a few fetch requests and returns a json object with data. How could I access this data with my chrome extension?

I've tried replacing the original fetch, like this:

```
let originalFetch = window.fetch;

async function newFetch(input, init) {
  return originalFetch(input, init).then(async(response) => {
    return response.text().then((text) => {
      console.log('load: ' + text);
      return new Response(text, { 'headers': response.headers, 'status': response.status });
    });
  });
}
window.fetch = newFetch;
```

But it doesn't seem to be catching all of the requests that I need it to. Any ideas? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The site is probably using XMLHttpRequest and not `fetch`.

Comment: I've separately attempted to use a method to replace the XMLHttpRequest method, but it also is not returning the correct responses still:

```let oldXHROpen = window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function(method, url, async, user, password) {
 this.addEventListener('load', function() {
  console.log('load: ' + this.responseText);
  
 });
               
 return oldXHROpen.apply(this, arguments);
}```

Comment: Note that this code must be injected in [page context](/a/9517879) using method 5 or registerContentScripts and it should be declared to run at `document_start`.